# How to add base64 image in konvajs.image source

Tags: jquery, konvajs

I'm trying to add the base64 image into the konvaJS image, but not able to add it. If someone can help me to do this it would be great.

Please check my code,

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'imgId',
    width: width,
    height: height
});
konvasStage = stage;

// add canvas element
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var darthVaderGroup = new Konva.Group({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    draggable: false
});
layer.add(darthVaderGroup);

// darth vader
let darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});

var imageObj1 = new Image();
imageObj1.onload = function() {
    darthVaderImg.image(imageObj1);
    layer.draw();
};
imageObj1.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAI0lEQVQYV2NkQAb7//9nhPP3///P4MjICBGAckBMRmQOSAAAgboLwv3ivvAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a Snippet or JSFidle for more details of your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add `darthVaderImg` into the scene:

```
let darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});
darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
```

https://jsbin.com/rifazetowo/edit?html,js,output